# How to send mail in simple_jwt_login wordpress plugin hook?

Tags: wordpress, hook

I am using this plugin for Wordpress:
https://simplejwtlogin.com/docs/hooks/#1-simple_jwt_login_login_hook

When someone logs in on my external app through rest api, I want wordpress to send email by triggering the hook:

`functions.php`

```
add_action('simple_jwt_login_login_hook', 'my_test');
function my_test() {
    $to = 'you@yourmail.com';
    $subject = "Test mail";
    $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
    $from = "me@email.com";
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
    $headers[] = "From:" . "me@email.com";

    wp_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
```

I also have "Easy SMTP" plugin installed and working properly (wp_mail() should go through my smtp mail)

I don't see any errors in error.log, nor anything in mail.log. Do you think the hook is getting triggered or not?

Comment: By default, no hooks are enabled. You need to check the one that you want to use (From Simple-JWT-Login). did you enable the hook?

Comment: Yes, I have it checked in the gui. Is there a good way to test if the hook is getting "triggered"?

Comment: You can try adding `die('dead');` as the first line of the function, but that is only if you can test the API endpoint

Answer (score 0):

make sure you enable `simple_jwt_login_login_hook`

to test the hook, just throw an error in it and see if its captured on error log

like this

```
add_action('simple_jwt_login_login_hook', function( $user ) {
    
    throw new Exception('I\'m here mortals');

}, 11 , 1);
```

or via init

```
add_action('init', function() {
    
    add_action('simple_jwt_login_login_hook', function( $user ) {
        
        throw new Exception('I\'m here mortals');

    }, 11, 1);
}, 99)
```